# IF statement with multiple SELECTs in MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm using MySQL with Visual Studio 2010 C# language.

I need to make a query.

```
SELECT a field, if this field is null or equals to 0
```

Make another `SELECT` and if it is different `<>` from `null` or `0`.
Make another `SELECT`.

I also tried to follow the suggestion that appears when you write the title above, but nothing.

Something Like:

```
SELECT cart.cod_dependent (if cart.cod_dependent <> 0, Select ass.matricula, ass.nome, ass.situacao_social, ass.categoria, ELSE IF cart.cod_dependent = null Make another select)
```

Each select will be in different Tables, but all in the same database.

------ UPDATE 10/08/2012 09:59  --------
Now I'm Trying what you said **Radu Bompa**, but it says "fatal error encoutering during the Execution command" =\ .

```
 MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
  string sql = @"SELECT @cod_dep = cart.cod_dependente FROM carteiras as cart
  IF @cod_dep IS NULL
  BEGIN
  SELECT ass.matricula, ass.nome, ass.situacao_social, ass.categoria FROM associados AS ass INNER JOIN categorias AS cat ON cat.codigo = ass.categoria,
  INNER JOIN situacoes_social AS ss ON ass.situacao_social = ss.codigo
  END
  ELSE
  BEGIN
  SELECT dep.nome, dep.matricula, dep.situacao_social, ss.descricao FROM dependentes INNER JOIN situacao_social as ss dep.situacao_social = ss.codigo
  END
  WHERE cart.numero = @carteira";
  cmd.CommandText = sql;
  cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
  string dependente = "";
  cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@carteira", MySqlDbType.Int32)).Value = carteira;
  DataSet ds = _dal.Consultar(cmd);
```

Comment: I'm trying to do this too, but creating a `view` so I can't use `@variable` assignments. Any related answers? I guess try BEGIN and END?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this could work:

```
SELECT @SomeValue = cart.cod_dependent FROM cart   
--@SomeValue is a variable, declared for this purpose
IF @SomeValue IS NULL
BEGIN
  SELECT ass.matricula, ass.nome, ass.situacao_social, ass.categoria FROM table2
END
ELSE
BEGIN
  SELECT field FROM table3
END
```

You could also try to use a [stored procedure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa174792%28v=sql.80%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for answering me Radu Bompa, but tell me, this @SomeValue is just a 'thing' you use to compare, like the queryes we use to Execute with MySqlcommand.Parameter.Add(new MySq [...]); ? Or I DO have to compare it with a certain value ? I'll try without a certain value, thanks again.

Comment: In the SELECT statement you don't have to compare SomeValue, the comparison is made in the IF statement, by using IS NULL.

Comment: Please if its not too much, take a look at my update post and see what's wrong... Thank you